# como mostrar a saída por extenso de um laço de repetição no console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console

Tenho um exemplo bem simplista de código. **Segue Ex.:**

```js
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
  console.log("alguma coisa");
}
```

No *Chrome DevTools* não aparece bem a saída que eu esperava, a saída é algo análoga a representação da quantidade de vezes que a saída executou, seguida da saída em si. **Ex.:** `5 alguma coisa`

Tem como alterar esse padrão?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom não é a melhor maneira mas vc pode tentar isso:

**1 ->** Pressione **F12** (Abre o painel de 'debug')

**2 ->** Pressione **F1** ou clique nas '3 bolinhas do painel' ao lado do **X** e clique em settings (Abre as config do painel)

**3 ->** Na parte de Console, ative a opção **Show timestamps**.

Comment: A melhor maneira é a que funcione, e funcionou. valeu!

Comment: Disponha, é um prazer poder ajudar. :D